# Can not install app from PlayStore for Android 12 targetSDK 31

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, android-12

Recently User can download the app but after download, app is not getting install

I've added `android:exported="true"` in manifest but still facing the issue, If there is anything that I'm missing the please help me to solve it.

`build.gradle`

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "packagename"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 27
        versionName "2.14"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

`AndroidManifest`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="---">

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="AppName"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:showWhenLocked="true"
            android:turnScreenOn="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
           
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="appdomain.ca"
                    android:pathPrefix="/user"
                    android:scheme="https" />
                <data
                    android:host="appdomain.ca"
                    android:pathPrefix="/post"
                    android:scheme="https" />
                <data
                    android:host="appdomain.ca"
                    android:pathPrefix="/business"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notification" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="high_importance_channel" />
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was with **the old version** of `flutter_local_notifications`. So if anyone facing the same issue then first **update your all dependencies** then move ahead.

Comment: You save my life <3 :v

Answer (score 1):

Did you try deleted `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`. Because it's field does not work when targetSDKVersion is 31.

Comment: still the same, cant install